# Show that $X$ is separable.

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, compactness, order-theory, filters

I'm working through Kunen's Set Theory and I'm not sure how to proceed on part of one exercise.  Let $X$ be compact Hausdorff and $\mathbb{O}_X$ be the poset of nonempty open sets of $X$ ordered by inclusion. I want to show that all of

1. $X$ is separable.
2. $\mathbb{O}_X$ is $\sigma$-centered.
3. $\mathbb{O}_X$ is a countable union of filters.

are equivalent.  I have 3 $\Rightarrow$ 2 and 1 $\Rightarrow$ 3.  For 2 $\Rightarrow$ 1, we have that $\mathbb{O}_X=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N} C_n$ where each $C_n$ is centered, but I'm not sure how from these I should pick the points in the countable dense subset.  Also, I haven't used the compact Hausdorff hypotheses yet and I am not sure how they will come into play.

Comment: what does $\sigma$-centered mean?

Comment: @Stefan: A poset $\langle P,\le\rangle$ is centred if for each finite $F\subseteq P$ there is a $p\in P$ such that $p\le q$ for each $q\in F$. A poset is $\sigma$-centred if it is the union of countably many centred posets.

Comment: I don't think the topology is a countable union of filters since filters are closed under supersets and a topology is not. Do you mean filter bases?

Comment: @Stefan: Filters in the partial order $\langle\Bbb O_x,\subseteq\rangle$, not in $\langle\wp(X),\subseteq\rangle$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Thanks. I think I have to learn about those filters, too. Only ever dealt with filters of sets.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: So a poset is centered if its dual is directed?

Comment: @Stefan: The [WP article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_%28mathematics%29#General_definition) together with its cross-references is a reasonable place to start.

Comment: @dfeuer: Yes. The notion also generalizes the finite intersection property.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Yes, I'm already reading it. Seems like a filter on a set is simply a filter in the poset $(\mathcal P(X),\subseteq)$.

Comment: @Stefan: That’s exactly right, though I’m pretty sure that historically the set filters came first.

Comment: This seems as good a place as any to mention two terminological points. First, one speaks (or at least one should speak) of filters  *in* posets and filters *on* or *over* sets --- exactly as Stefan did in his comment here. Correct use of the prepositions here can save a lot of confusion in those situations where one actually needs a filter on a set that happens to also have a partial ordering.  Second, "centered" and "centred" are (fortunately) the same; the former is American and the latter English (or should I say British?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\Bbb O_X=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}\Bbb O_n$, where each $\Bbb O_n$ is centred. For $n\in\omega$ let $K_n=\bigcap\{\operatorname{cl}U:U\in\Bbb O_n\}$; use the fact that $X$ is compact to conclude that $K_n\ne\varnothing$. For $n\in\omega$ let $x_n\in K_n$, and let $D=\{x_n:n\in\omega\}$. Now let $U$ be any non-empty open set in $X$; since $X$ is compact and Hausdorff, $X$ is regular, and there is a non-empty open $V$ such that $\operatorname{cl}V\subseteq U$. There is an $n\in\omega$ such that $V\in\Bbb O_n$, so $$x_n\in D\cap K_n\subseteq D\cap\operatorname{cl}V\subseteq D\cap U\;,$$ and it follows that $D$ is dense in $X$.

Comment: Do you mean "compact" instead of "Hausdorff" in the second line?

Comment: @Stefan: I sure do; thanks!